# How to format a Python string to resemble a dictionary using .format()?

Tags: python, string, printing, formatting

I have a python variable containing the string `A` and another one containing the string `B`.

I want to generate the string which represents the dictionary containing the aforementioned two strings as a key value pair. How can I do it? Using nested curly brackets inside a string literal seems not to work. But I need that notation to use `.format()`

```
>>> x = "A"
>>> y = "B"
>>> assert(eval('\{"{}": "{}"\}'.format(x, y)) == str({x: y}))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '"{}"
```

Comment: Weird question.  What's wrong with `repr({x:y})`?

Comment: Escape with double braces `{{"{}": "{}"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape curly braces by adding double curly braces i.e `{{` and `}}`.

To generate the string:

```
>>> x = 'A'
>>> y = 'B'
>>> dict_str = "{{'{}': '{}'}}".format(x,y)
>>> dict_str
"{'A': 'B'}"
```